# Workaround for AS3 language bug?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, localization, keyboard

Does anyone know how to fix the bugs in Actionscript / Flash regarding keyboard input of European characters?

Entering, for example portuguese characters, works fine on PC, but not MAC, this bug is on both Flash 9 and 10.

These does not work: Á, Â, Ã, À, Ç, É, Ê, Í, Ó, Ô, Õ, Ú. 
Works sometimes (but typically only the first time): ç

Please note, this is not an embed problem, pasting the characters works fine. It is just the flash to keyboard user-input which does not support entry.

On the Mac's we have tested this on, we have not been using a Portuguese keyboard, if this makes any difference, I don't know.

Comment: are you using wmode transparent or opaque?

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known problem](http://www.johanvanmol.org/content/view/47/41/) when using special wmodes in combination with firefox. the simplest solution by far is to avoid those wmodes.